# Oracle SQL update statement how to update two rows at a time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I tried to update two rows in a table. 
If I used:

```
update ERNTESTUPDATE a
set (date_loaded, acad_career) = (select distinct b.date_loaded, b.acad_career
from PS_STDNT_ENRL b
where rownum=1)
where to_char(date_created) = to_char(trunc(sysdate))
;
```

I got 2 rows updated as

```
11/29/18 UGRD
11/29/18 UGRD
```

If I used:

```
update ERNTESTUPDATE a
set (date_loaded, acad_career) = (select distinct b.date_loaded, b.acad_career
from PS_STDNT_ENRL b
where a.date_loaded = b.date_loaded )
where to_char(date_created) = to_char(trunc(sysdate))
;
```

I got an error

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

How to get a result as below:

```
11/29/18 UGRD
11/29/18 GRAD
```

Thank you, 
Kate

Comment: Test case might help; you posted some queries, but - what data do they deal with?

Answer (score 0):

The subquery needs to return a SINGLE row. That works well when you include the condition `rownum=1` in the first one:

```
select distinct b.date_loaded, b.acad_career
from PS_STDNT_ENRL b 
where rownum=1 -- this filter makes sure only one row is returned
```

If you remove that condition, then the subquery will return multiple rows, and that makes the whole `UPDATE` fail.